# Hammerfist Giant with Lifelink?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have a [Hammerfist Giant](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHammerfist%20Giant%5d) with a [Felidar Umbra](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFelidar%20Umbra%5d) on it (enchantment aura that gives the creature Lifelink). There are 3 players and 7 non-flying creatures on the battlefield. I tap the giant to deal 4 damage to each player and non-flying creature. Do I gain 4 life, or do I gain 40 life?

Answer (score 7):

### 40 life.

Hammerfist Giant is dealing 40 total damage, so you gain 40 total life.

Comment: First, I'm pretty sure that in cases where it would actually matter, this would not actually count as multiple second instances of damage, and second, it doesn't actually matter here whether they are separate instances of damage, what matters is that it's dealing a total of 40 damage.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Yeah, you're right.  Fixed.

Comment: @murgatroid99, Depends on the wording. "Damage dealt": One instance. "Damage dealt by a source": One instance. "Damage dealt to a creature or player": 10 instances, "Damage dealt by a source to a creature or player": 10 instances. etc. Lifelink uses "damage dealt by a source", so one instance.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Not sure what you mean by "second" instances, but they are indeed separate instances of damage and lifegain. For this question it doesn't matter, but it matters for replacement effects (such as damage increase/reduction/prevention) and triggered abilities such as Ajani's Pridemate.

Comment: That extra "second" was just a typo. The lifelink rules say that if multiple **sources** deal damage simultaneously, that counts as separate instances of lifegain, but this is just one source dealing a bunch of damage all at once, so it counts as one lifegain event.

Comment: @Hackworth, Re "*they are indeed separate instances of [...] lifegain*", My earlier comment explains this is not the case. Ajani's Pridemate would only trigger once.